# MongoDB - Is it possible to only insert a record when the record doesn't exist

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I have a database with custom ids and I only want to insert a new record if the id is different from the other ids. If the id exists I don't want to update the value (so I think upsert isn't a solution for me).

I'm using the pymongo connector.

Example Database:

```
[
  {"_id": 1, "name": "john"},
  {"_id": 2, "name": "paul"}
]
```

Comment: The `_id` is unique - you can't have dups.

Comment: why you think upsert doesnt work?

Comment: @DaveStSomeWhere Do I otherwise will get an error?

Comment: @varman Because I don't want to update the record

Comment: Yes, you'll get an error - please test it and see for yourself, you'll get something like `DuplicateKeyError: E11000 duplicate key error collection:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trap and ignore the `DuplicateKeyError`, e.g.:

```
pymongo import MongoClient
from pymongo.errors import DuplicateKeyError

db = MongoClient()['mydatabase']

records = [
  {"_id": 1, "name": "john"},
  {"_id": 2, "name": "paul"},
  {"_id": 3, "name": "ringo"}
]

for record in records:
    try:
        db.mycollection.insert_one(record)
        print (f'Inserted {record}')
    except DuplicateKeyError:
        print (f'Skipped duplicate {record}')
        pass
```

Result (something like):

```
Skipped duplicate {'_id': 1, 'name': 'john'}
Skipped duplicate {'_id': 2, 'name': 'paul'}
Inserted {'_id': 3, 'name': 'ringo'}
```